# Reset a JS Object - Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using the Dragslider (http://code.ovidiu.ch/dragdealer/) JS library to create a nice slider effect to input data into a very graphical form within a HTML5 site.

All works fine  - however once the slider has been used and the correct percentage stored in the form - I need to allow the user to then edit the result - which would mean passing the current figure from the input box into the js constructor, there is a method (setValue) available to do this when constructing the slider - but as its already constructed I need a way to remove and re-enable the script with the new start figure.

At the moment the slider is initiated with this command -

```
    new Dragdealer('bol-slider',animationCallback: function(x)
        {

    //animation commands
            }
        )
```

Is it possible to stop/remove the dragdealer object via JS and re-initiate with a constructor containing the relevant start figure?

Comment: What happens when you just run the construct code again?  It's quite normal with jQuery plugins to do that.

Comment: it screws up basically - it applies the correct number but the slider remains in the previous position!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation, it looks like you can call its methods at any time, you don't need to do it during construction. An example from that page:

```
link1.onclick = function()
{
    slideshow.setStep(1);
    return false;
}
```

They call the setStep method on the click of a link, but you can replace with your setValue method. You might call it on a [focusout event](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/) or similar, like:

```
$('#yourinput').on('focusout', function(){
    yourslider.setValue(3);
});
```